# Run OpenJFX with OpenJDK 8?

Tags: java, openjfx

I try to run a OpenJDK 8 app with a JavaFX (openjfx) UI. When I try to compile my code I get the following error: class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0.

So my question: Are they not compatible in general?

I wonder because under OpenJDK 11 it seems to work (at least the compilation) but
I don't find something about that on the web.

I know that the Error means that there is a mix of different Java versions, but I wonder how this is possible. Is the OpenJFX only available as binary for Java11?

Note: I include openjfx version 11 via maven into my project.

Comment: How are you compiling your application?  On JDK 11?  By default, that means you'll need JDK 11 or later to run.  Compiled Java code has a "version" requirement embedded in it.  You need to set the `--release 8` option to `javac` to run your application under Java 8.  That might not be compatible with your source code your with using openJFX 11, however.  And you haven't mentioned how you build your application other than your mention of `maven`, so I don't have an exact answer for you.

Comment: As @baliman answered previously, the OpenJFX jar was compiled with Java 11 evidently. Take an earlier version.

Comment: I use the earliest version I can find already (11-ea+19). I compile with IntelliJ and maven. I can only enable --release for java 9 in the compiler UI of IntelliJ :(.

Comment: You can try ZuluFX, which is a build of OpenJDK with OpenJFX included. They currently have version 8 and 11 (though not 11 for Linux, not sure why).

Comment: I am also facing the same issue while trying to include openjfx with OpenJDK but have not found any workaround till now. If you have a solution, please let me know